# Keycloak Custom realm properties/settings

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm creating a new Keycloak(v18.0.1) provider that will perform an action (make an http call/send a message to a queue, etc...) when a user is created/edited/deleted, the purpose is to keep a service specific copy of the user in another micro-service.

I started by implementing **EventListenerProviderFactory** and was able to intercept the events that I need.

**Problem**

Our keycloack instance has multiple realms and we only want this functionality for specific realms.

Ideally I would like to design a section/tab under realm settings that will have a toggle that I read its value from my custom provider along with other properties/urls about the destination of the event.

I've checked a lot of examples online and I found that **UserStorageProviderFactory** has this method which you can override:

```
    @Override
public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
    return ProviderConfigurationBuilder.create()
        .property(Constants.BASE_URL, "Base URL", "Base URL of the API", ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE, "", null)
        ...........
        .build();
}
```

Unfortunately this is not available for **EventListenerProviderFactory** so is there a way to store realm specific settings that can be edited in the UI? It doesn't not matter if the settings show up in the UI in some other place as long as I'm able to read using my provider.

Comment: Maybe this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389150/adding-more-attributes-to-realm-settings

Comment: @csbrogi this implements another provider to configure realm, which I don't really want, but thanks for the information.